# Whats the easiest way to put a long SQL code into VBA Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, containers, postgresql-9.6

We have a code that is quite long, that we want to put into VBA Excel. For extracting the outstanding balance of all our customers account (we're a bank sort of). But To write the code takes to long because we have to reformat it etc etc..... So what do you suggest we use?

Im not sure wether I should put in what we've thought about, I don't want to steer your recommendations here.....But we've looked into FUNCTIONS, PROCEDURES and VIEWS. All for the purpose of finding lets call it a "container" which we can put our code in and then put it into VBA, and then make sure that it understands what is inside this container, so that it executes the code and gets us the outstanding balance + some more info.
Thannks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running SQL file from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043116/running-sql-file-from-vba)

Comment: Why do you want to put existing code in to Excel specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a SQL VIEW / Stored Proc is a better idea than creating queries in Excel. It'll be pre-compiled so will run quicker, and it means you can call it from other places than Excel.

If you put all the definition for a query in Excel, then you'll need to use Excel to get that same info, or copy that Excel routine to somewhere else (and that's when mistakes start to happen). Adhere to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

I would just create a stored SQL procedure or a VIEW, server-side and then just call it from Excel with whatever parameters you like to pull in the right data, keep it nice and simple on the Excel side.

Comment: YES IT BLOODY WELL WORKED @JAMHEADART !!!! THANK YOU MAN